# Program received Signal SIGABRT when scrolling up UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

When i scroll my UITableView down and then scrolling up, the app crashes with the stack below:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2147483647 beyond bounds [0 .. 48]'
```

I know it's saying that i am accessing a cell index that exceed the UITableView size, but i am not able to figure out how to fix it. this may be my relevant code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CheckedTableViewCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *rowData = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:[self tableIndexFromIndexPath:indexPath]];//this line may be the source of the crash
    cell.textLabel.text = [rowData objectForKey:kCellTextKey];

    if ([[rowData objectForKey:kCellStateKey] boolValue]) {
        UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"]];
        cell.accessoryView = imageView1;    
    } else {
        UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"]];
        cell.accessoryView = imageView2;
    }

    return cell;
    }
```

**EDIT**:

Here is my `tableIndexFromIndexPath` method implementation

```
- (NSUInteger)tableIndexFromIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Get list of items at selected section
    NSArray *listData = [tableContents objectForKey:[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    // Get name of selected row within the section
    NSString *textKey = [listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Look up that name in the tableData array
    for (int i=0; i < [tableData count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [tableData objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([[dict objectForKey:kCellTextKey] isEqualToString:textKey]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    //In case Name was not found 
    return NSNotFound;
}
```

Comment: What your tableIndexFromIndexPath method does?

Comment: @Malek - agree with the comment in code, what does `tableIndexFromIndexPath` looks like?

Comment: I have edited my post, actually, in the `tableIndexFromIndexPath` method i take into account the case where a name from my UITableView is not found and i return `NSNotFound`.

Comment: And when you return `NSNotFound`, it tries to look that index up in the array and you get the exception.

Comment: I think your count of numberOfRows exceeds your total of array count

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
NSDictionary *rowData = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:[self tableIndexFromIndexPath:indexPath]];
```

to

```
NSDictionary *rowData = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Hi `blake305`, actually, i can't change it, because i work with two Mutable arrays(my UITableView is divided into sections), otherwise when i select a cell i one section, it will check randomly other cells in other sections, please have a look on my Update :)

Answer (score 0):

As several have noted, your `tableIndexFromIndexPath:` is incorrect. Specifically it's returning `NSNotFound`, which suggests your using something like `indexOfObject:` for an object that is not in the array.

Answer (score 0):

1. At first check that are you getting all value of your `NSMutableArray`?
2. If you are getting then check your number of section of tableView is equal to number of `NSMutableArray` array or not?
3. If same then there is a reload problem then reload your table view when you are inserting data into the `NSMutableArray`.

I hope you will find your solution among them.